# Group by day using $dateToString in C# MondoDB Driver 2

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I want to group an aggregate by day (not dayOfMonth or Year, just absolute day). Therefore I want to use the `$dateToString` operator as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27607992/498298): `$dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$date" }`. Is there a way to use an expression for this like:

```
var groups = await collection.Aggregate()
    .Match(job => /*...*/)
    .Group(job => job.Created.ToString(), 
           group => /*...*/)
    .ToListAsync();
```

I get this error:

> ToString of type System.DateTime is not supported in the expression tree {document}{created}.ToString...

Comment: I actually could not think of a worse choice for a grouping key for a BSON `Date` than a "string". It's so unnecessary and really so "not useful" in returned data. I am unashamedly "proud" of the [answer to date grouping here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26814427/2313887), and not just for my own input ( disclaimer but not ashamed of it) on the matter. Because the original answer is IMHO quite great as well. It's worth a read.

Comment: @BlakesSeven Thx a lot. I didn't realize that I can use a more complex grouping key.

Comment: In all honesty the [`$dateToString`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/) operator was introduced due to "horrible misuse" ( and mostly from answers on this site <grins> )of the [`$substr`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/) operator along with other [date aggregation operators](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/) to do the same thing that it does (sort of). If you don't mind, I'd love to put a "duplicate" mark to the two questions to indicate the link.

Answer (score 2):

With the help of [@Blakes Seven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5031275/blakes-seven)s comment, I solved the original problem with another grouping key.

```
var groups = await collection.Aggregate()
    .Match(job => /*...*/)
    .Group(job => new 
          { 
              Year = job.Created.Year, 
              Month = job.Created.Month, 
              Day = job.Created.Day
           }, 
           group => new { Key = group.Key, Value = group.Count() })
    .ToListAsync();
```

**Edit**

To support other periods than *day*, I had to use a `BsonDocument`.

```
var groupBy = new BsonDocument
{
  {
    "_id", new BsonDocument
    {
        { "$add", new BsonArray
            {
                new BsonDocument
                {
                    { "$subtract", new BsonArray
                      {
                        new BsonDocument { { "$subtract", new BsonArray 
                          { 
                            "$created", 
                            new DateTime(0) } 
                          }   
                        new BsonDocument { { "$mod", new BsonArray  
                            {
                                new BsonDocument 
                                { 
                                  { "$subtract", new BsonArray 
                                    { 
                                      "$created", 
                                      new DateTime(0) 
                                    } 
                                  } 
                                },
                                msPerPeriod
                            }
                        } }
                      }
                    }
                },
                new DateTime(0)
            }
        }
    }
  },
  { "count", new BsonDocument("$sum", 1) } };


var groups = await collection.Aggregate()
    .Match(job => job.Created >= since && regex.IsMatch(job.Definition))
    .Group(groupBy)
    .Sort(Builders<BsonDocument>.Sort.Ascending(doc => doc["_id"]))
    .ToListAsync();
```

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32137234/498298

Comment: Whilst this is better than `$dateToString` in some respects. Using the "date math" approach to "rounding" a BSON Date is **much** better. And of course you can actually still return a BSON Date, which will become a "Date" Object as is commonly used in every driver if you do so. [Unashamed Plug](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32137234/5031275). IMHO, that's **much** better than a "string" or even a "composite key".

Comment: @BlakesSeven I don't get this into a Linq expression. C# `DateTime` `operator-` returns `TimeSpan` and I cannot apply a modulo on this. I tried `Ticks` but this cannot be translated...

Comment: Good point, and now you've just given me some homework ( Thanks, not! ). I kind of have the feeling that Linq is not going to "fit" here, and rather it needs to be a direct BSON expression. But I think it's worth a try at least. As "Arnie" says, *"I'll be back!"*

Comment: @BlakesSeven Have you done your homework? ;-) I'm using a `BsonDocument` now, to support weekly counts.