# MongoDb Aggregate , find duplicate records within 7 days

Tags: mongodb, duplicates, aggregation-framework

I have to create a check for this use case-

Duplicate payment check

• Same amount to a same account number in last 7 days for all transactions.

I haven't used mongoDb as much would have been easier for me to write in sql

This is what I am trying without the 7 days part

```
db.transactiondetails.aggregate({$group: {"_id":{"account_number":"$account_number","amount":"$amount"},"count": { $sum: 1 }}})
```

Where I get something like this :

```
{ "_id" : { "account_number" : "xxxxxxxy", "amount" : 19760 }, "count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : { "account_number" : "xxxxzzzz", "amount" : 20140 }, "count" : 2 }
...
```

I have `created_at` and `updated_at` which are date fields , I am using updated_at for duplicates

for example :

```
"created_at" : ISODate("2019-01-07T15:40:53.683Z"),
"updated_at" : ISODate("2019-01-09T06:48:44.839Z"),
```

In sql we can create groups of 7 days, for each date there will be a start date plus 7 days in which we need to find the duplicates.

It is running 7 day groups where I need to find duplicates.

Any help how to go about this will be appreciated.

Comment: Grouping by: `account_number` + `amount` + `diff(updated_at - created_at) < 7 days` resolves your use case?

Comment: @Valijon i think the answer is no as we need to address possible recursion, what he failed to mention is what defines a duplicate precisely, for example if we have 3 documents 5 days apart each with the same account and amount is the 3rd a duplicate of the 1st? a duplicate of the 2cd? is it not a duplicate? it is unclear.

Comment: @Valijon : I wanted something like this to aggregate records which are between the date range of 7 days from the current record with similar amount and account_number  ```{$gte : {$subtract : ["$updated_at" , (7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)]} , $other_updated_ats }```

Comment: I have a very similar example in MongoDB World aggregation presentation in 2017-2018, the code is here: https://github.com/asya999/mdbw17/blob/master/networkLogins.js

Comment: @AsyaKamsky Yes ```Find logins from different IPs within 10 minutes over specified time period ``` , seems to be the same case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if this meets your requirements:

### Explanation

1. We sort documents (I assume you have indexes). We need it to iterate array in the next steps.
2. We group by `account_number` + `amount` and create arrays (`data`, `tmp`) with documents
3. We `$unwind` (flatten) `tmp` array to calculate how many days past for item <sub>**i**</sub> to item <sub>**i+1 - n**</sub>
4. We count how many duplicates we have for different dates
5. Skip all `counts = 0`

---

```
db.transactiondetails.aggregate([
  {
    $sort: {
      account_number: 1,
      amount: 1,
      updated_at: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": {
        "account_number": "$account_number",
        "amount": "$amount"
      },
      "data": {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      },
      "tmp": {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$tmp"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: {
        account_number: "$_id.account_number",
        amount: "$_id.amount",
        updated_at: "$tmp.updated_at"
      },
      data: {
        $map: {
          input: {
            $slice: [
              "$data",
              {
                $add: [
                  {
                    $indexOfArray: [
                      "$data",
                      "$tmp"
                    ]
                  },
                  1
                ]
              },
              {
                $size: "$data"
              }
            ]
          },
          in: {
            "_id": "$$this._id",
            "account_number": "$$this.account_number",
            "amount": "$$this.amount",
            "created_at": "$$this.created_at",
            "updated_at": "$$this.updated_at",
            "days": {
              $divide: [
                {
                  $subtract: [
                    "$$this.updated_at",
                    "$tmp.updated_at"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $multiply: [
                    24,
                    60,
                    60,
                    1000
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      count: {
        $size: {
          $filter: {
            input: "$data",
            cond: {
              $lte: [
                "$$this.days",
                7
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "count": {
        $gt: 0
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/33Ki29FYtnv)

Comment: Seems good. I have been running 38 queries for each day for a month, i.e. for each day query between the past seven days and today if there are any duplicates. This seems good too.