# How to "CAST" a Time field as Date in Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I am using Mongoid as my Rails app's ORM and have a problem with one grouping issue.
The collection/model is basically a transaction log with timestamps and I would like to do some grouping based on the date part of the timestamp.

The model looks like this:

```
class Bounty
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :ts, type: Time
  field :char_id, type: Integer
  field :bounty, type: Integer
  index({ ts: 1, char_id: 1 }, { unique: true })
end
```

... and the grouping I'm looking for would be the equivalent of:

`SELECT CAST(ts as date), char_id, sum(bounty) from bounties group by CAST(ts as date), char_id;`

So far I was able to solve most of my group/sum problems with aggregations but in this case I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Take a look at these operators : http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/#date-operators

Comment: Thanks @attish that helped. My searching skills are lacking, I've been there and somehow missed the date operators :)

Comment: @attish I recommend you to rewrite your comment as an Answer so somebody else can benefit from your answer.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB now provides an aggregation framework that makes this a bit easier.  Mongoid also provides an interface to the MongoDB map/reduce framework that you have to use to do these sort of aggregations.  See [this description of the aggregation framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5168904/group-by-dates-in-mongodb) and Mongoid's [explanation of the map/reduce interface](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/querying.html#map_reduce)