# Conditionally group and sum of the elements from an array

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to group by `APPName` and I want find how many `PrestoBarImpression`, `PrestoKeyCountChange`, `PrestoTileImpression` for every application for a particular day (just the sum of order counts).

This is so I can generate a report with this information.  I need how many order counts of PrestoTileImpression, how many order counts of PrestoBarImpression, how many order counts of PrestoTileClick for every application.

The below is my Document.

```
{
    "ClientId": "XYZ123",
    "location": {
    "Name": "Hyderabad",
    "Country": "India",
    "Zip": "500084",
    "Gps": {
        "lat": "17.463607",
        "lon": "78.344279"
    }
    },
    "Network": {
    "Operator": "Airtel",
    "Type": "wifi",
    "TowerID": "123",
    "IP": "1.1.1.1"
    },
    "SessionTimeStamp": {
    "Start": ISODate("2015-06-02T05:36:49.045        Z"),
    "End": ISODate("2015-06-02T05:36:56.045        Z"),
    "Duration": "7000"
    },
    "AppName": "WhatsApp",
    "Text": "Key1 Key2 Key3 Key4",
    "Actions": [{
    "Type": "PrestoBarImpression",
    "CampaignId": 1,
    "keyword": "key1",
    "prestoCount": 1,
    "duration": 100,
    "OrderCount": 1
    }, {
    "Type": "PrestoKeyCountChange",
    "CampaignId": 1,
    "keyword": "key1",
    "prestoCount": 1,
    "OrderCount": 2
    }, {
    "Type": "PrestoBarImpression",
    "CampaignId": 2,
    "keyword": "key2",
    "prestoCount": 2,
    "duration": 150,
    "OrderCount": 3
    }, {
    "Type": "PrestoKeyCountChange",
    "CampaignId": "2",
    "keyword": "key2",
    "prestoCount": 2,
    "OrderCount": 4
    }, {
    "Type": "PrestoBarImpression",
    "CampaignId": 1,
    "keyword": "key3",
    "prestoCount": 2,
    "duration": 200,
    "OrderCount": 5
    }, {
    "Type": "PrestoTileImpression",
    "CampaignId": 1,
    "duration": 200,
    "OrderCount": 6
    }, {
    "Type": "PrestoTileImpression",
    "AdditionalAction": "swipeRight",
    "CampaignId": 2,
    "duration": 200,
    "OrderCount": 7
    }, {
    "Type": "PrestoTileClick",
    "AdditionalAction": "swipeRight",
    "CampaignId": 2,
    "OrderCount": 8
    }, {
    "Type": "PrestoBarImpression",
    "CampaignId": 2,
    "keyword": "key4",
    "prestoCount": 2,
    "duration": 150,
    "OrderCount": 9
    }]
}
```

I got the below output by using @Viswas response I made a query.

**Query**

```
[  
{  
    "$match":{  
        "SessionTimeStamp.Start":{  
            "$gte":                ISODate("2015-06-01T18:30:00.000                Z"),
            "$lte":                ISODate("2015-06-04T18:29:59.000                Z")
        }
    }
},
{  
    "$unwind":"$Actions"
},
{  
    "$match":{  
        "Actions.Type":{  
            "$in":[  
                "PrestoBarImpression",
                "PrestoKeyCountChange",
                "PrestoTileImpression"
            ]
        }
    }
},
{  
    "$group":{  
        "_id":{  
            "AppName":"$AppName",
            "type":"$Actions.Type"
        },
        "total":{  
            "$sum":"$Actions.OrderCount"
        }
    }
},
{  
    "$sort":{  
        "total":1,

    }
}
```

]

**Output**

```
{  
"result":[  
    {  
        "_id":{  
            "AppName":"WhatsApp",
            "type":"PrestoKeyCountChange"
        },
        "total":6
    },
    {  
        "_id":{  
            "AppName":"hike",
            "type":"PrestoKeyCountChange"
        },
        "total":6
    },
    {  
        "_id":{  
            "AppName":"hike",
            "type":"PrestoTileImpression"
        },
        "total":13
    },
    {  
        "_id":{  
            "AppName":"WhatsApp",
            "type":"PrestoTileImpression"
        },
        "total":13
    },
    {  
        "_id":{  
            "AppName":"hike",
            "type":"PrestoBarImpression"
        },
        "total":18
    },
    {  
        "_id":{  
            "AppName":"WhatsApp",
            "type":"PrestoBarImpression"
        },
        "total":18
    }
],
"ok":1.0000000000000000
```

}

**I need the output in below format**

```
[  
{  
    "AppName":"WhatsApp",
    " PrestoTileImpression":13,
    "PrestoKeyCountChange":6,
    "PrestoBarImpression":18,
    "count":"10 (This is how many times thee Application presents in document, because I need to find top 10 apps Need to sort the output by this count)"
},
{  
    "AppName":"Hike",
    " PrestoTileImpression":13,
    "PrestoKeyCountChange":6,
    "PrestoBarImpression":18,
    "count":"10 "
}
```

]

Comment: This is the document

Comment: "The below"?? There is no document there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [group by dates in mongodb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5168904/group-by-dates-in-mongodb)

Comment: Also, please try to come up with a more descriptive question title. Questions should be titled in a way that someone who has the same problem can find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/) to get result.

If you want **`ActionType` wise `OrderCount`** for **given date (particular)** date then you need to first match `start` to your date and then `group` data according to `Action.Type`.
 The query will be as following:

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    $match: {
    "SessionTimeStamp.Start": ISODate("2015-06-02T05:36:49.045Z")
    }
}, {
    $group: {
    "_id": "AppName",
    "Document": {
        $push: {
            "SessionTimeStamp": "$SessionTimeStamp",
            "Actions": "$Actions",
            "AppName": "$AppName"
        }
    }
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$Document"
}, {
    $unwind: "$Document.Actions"
}, {
    $group: {
    _id: "$Document.Actions.Type",
    "OrderCount": {
        $sum: "$Document.Actions.OrderCount"
    },
    "App": {
        $first: "$Document.AppName"
    }
    }
}, {
    $project: {
    "_id": 0,
    "OrderCount": 1,
    "ActionType": "$_id",
    "App": 1
    }
})
```

**Edit after comment of question author:**

[Reference to Duplicate Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30932758/mongo-db-query-group-by-and-conditional) by author

**Please verify spelling of `count` for `appNames` as it is different (`count`, `Count`) for some `appName`s**

You should use following query-

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    $match: {
    "SessionTimeStamp.Start": {
        $gte: ISODate("2015-06-02T05:36:49.045Z")
    },
    "SessionTimeStamp.End": {
        $lte: ISODate("2015-06-02T05:36:56.045Z")
    }
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$Actions"
}, {
    $group: {
    "_id": {
        "AppName": "$AppName",
        "Type": "$Actions.Type"
    },
    "count": {
        "$sum": "$Actions.Count"
    },
    "appCount": {
        $sum: 1
    }
    }
}, {
    $project: {
    "AppName": "$_id.AppName",
    "Type": "$_id.Type",
    "count": 1,
    "appCount": 1,
    "_id": 0
    }
})
```

If you still want to assign dynamic values as keys then you can iterate over the cursor you get like -

```
db.collection.aggregate({$match:{"SessionTimeStamp.Start":{$gte:ISODate("2015-06-02T05:36:49.045Z")},
"SessionTimeStamp.End":{$lte:ISODate("2015-06-02T05:36:56.045Z")}}},
{$unwind:"$Actions"},{$group:{"_id":{"AppName":"$AppName","Type":"$Actions.Type"},
"count":{"$sum":"$Actions.Count"},"appCount":{$sum:1}}},
{$project:{"AppName":"$_id.AppName","Type":"$_id.Type","count":1,
"appCount":1,"_id":0}}).forEach( function(myDoc){  var feeType = {}; 
feeType["AppName"] = myDoc.AppName; feeType[myDoc.Type]= myDoc.count;
feeType["appCount"] = myDoc.appCount; printjson (feeType);})
```

Answer (score 1):

It's really all about filtering the array content to get just the items you want in the sum:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    // Filter documents with matching entries first
    { "$match": {
        "Actions.Type": { "$in": [
            "PrestoBarImpression",
            "PrestoKeyCountChange",
            "PrestoTileImpression"
        ]}
    }},
    // Unwind the array entries
    { "$unwind": "$Actions" },
    // Filter to only keep desired array entries
    { "$match": {
        "Actions.Type": { "$in": [
            "PrestoBarImpression",
            "PrestoKeyCountChange",
            "PrestoTileImpression"
        ]}
    }},
    // Group by AppName and current day (finishing)
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "AppName": "$AppName",
            "day": {
                "year": { "$year": "$SessionTimeStamp.End" },
                "month": { "$month": "$SessionTimeStamp.End" },
                "day": { "$dayOfMonth": "$SessionTimeStamp.End" }
            },
            "type": "$Actions.Type"
        },
        "total": { "$sum": "$Actions.OrderCount" }
    }},
    // Sort as however you require
    { "$sort": {
        "_id.AppName": 1,
        "_id.day": 1,
        "_id.type": 1,
        "total": -1
    }}
])
```

Or if you want all those fields per document then right after the existing group add:

```
{ "$group": {
    "_id": {
        "AppName": "$_id.AppName",
        "day": "$_id.day",
     },
     "PrestoBarImpression": { "$sum": {
         "$cond": [
             { "$eq": [ "$_id.type", "PrestoBarImpression" ] },
             "$total",
             0
         ]
     }},
     "PrestoKeyCountChange": { "$sum": {
         "$cond": [
             { "$eq": [ "$_id.type", "PrestoKeyCountChange" ] },
             "$total",
             0
         ]
     }},
     "PrestoTileImpression": { "$sum": {
         "$cond": [
             { "$eq": [ "$_id.type", "PrestoTileImpression" ] },
             "$total",
             0
         ]
     }}
}}
```

Which tallies the totals per field into single documents for "AppName" and "day".

You probably want to add a "date range" match to that first `$match` pipeline rather than add up everything in the collection and just do so between dates as well.

Comment: Thanks for answer, However I need the PrestoBarImpression, PrestoTileImpression..etc ordercounts independently

Comment: @kirankumarreddy No problem. It's a simple change and already done. You really need to be "very clear" in your questions and preferably show some expected output as well as your input document.