# MongoDB aggregate Query for to get a total count

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am trying to find the sum of all commission  per day but I don't know what should I do and the below is the mongoDB documents:

```
"operationData" : {
    "topUp" : {
        "topUpId" : "20160520182653940+043000001792098779520",
        "phoneNumber" : "792098779",
        "commission" : 4,
    }
}
}

{
    "_id" : 2,
    "dateTime" : ISODate("2016-06-20T13:56:53.970Z"),
    "operationData" : {
        "topUp" : {
            "topUpId" : "20160520182653940+043000001792098779520",
            "phoneNumber" : "792098779",
            "commission" : 6,
        }
    }
}

{
    "_id" : 3,
    "dateTime" : ISODate("2016-06-20T13:56:53.970Z"),
    "operationData" : {
        "topUp" : {
            "topUpId" : "20160520182653940+0430000017920987345243",
            "phoneNumber" : "792098779",
            "commission" : 5,
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried something already?

Comment: Possible dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5168904/group-by-dates-in-mongodb

Comment: did you find my answer useful?

Answer (score 1):

you need to use datetime operators [ref here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/)

**Name  Description**

1. $dayOfYear  Returns the day of the year for a date as a number between 1 and 366 (leap year).
2. $dayOfMonth Returns the day of the month for a date as a number between 1 and 31.
3. $dayOfWeek  Returns the day of the week for a date as a number between 1 (Sunday) and 7 (Saturday).
4. $year   Returns the year for a date as a number (e.g. 2014).
5. $month  Returns the month for a date as a number between 1 (January) and 12 (December).
6. $week   Returns the week number for a date as a number between 0 (the partial week that precedes the first Sunday of the year) and 53 (leap year).
7. $hour   Returns the hour for a date as a number between 0 and 23.
8. $minute Returns the minute for a date as a number between 0 and 59.
9. $second Returns the seconds for a date as a number between 0 and 60 (leap seconds).
10. $millisecond    Returns the milliseconds of a date as a number between 0 and 999.
11. $dateToString   Returns the date as a formatted string.

So you could have this snippet

```
db.operationData.aggregate([{
            $group : {
                _id : {
                    dayOfYear : {
                        $dayOfYear : "$dateTime"
                    },
                    year : {
                        $year : "$dateTime"
                    }
                },
                commission : {
                    $sum : "$operationData.topUp.commission"
                }
            }
        }
    ])
```