# MongoDB $group with datetime displays "None"

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, jupyter-notebook, pymongo

I started learning to use MongoDB along with Jupyter notebook and  the python module Pymongo.

In one of my documents, I store data as following:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("60b78821d5a53a1f12336580"),
  "num_arete" : "0",
  "date" : ISODate("2020-01-01T07:01:00Z"),
  "nb_vehicules" : "32"
}
```

I wanted, using aggregation, make the *$sum* of all the *nb_vehicules* within the document's collecions group by date.

Here's what I've tried:

```
passage_per_hour = collection_trafic.aggregate([{
    '$group': {
        '_id': '$date',
        'amount': { '$sum': {'$toInt' :'$nb_vehicules'}}
    }
}])
```

But when I run it inside the notenook, it doesn't perfom the group-by and display me *$date* as *None* (see below).

[image]

Do someone has any idea why ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by grouping by date? It's extremely unlikely that two documents will have the EXACT same date, so there won't be any grouping with the aggregation you did. Does this answer on another question help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/16724320/7133623

Comment: I know my query is more complex but I made this simple example because the problem seems to came from the date.

Comment: Collection names on the screenshot differ.  The result says there are no single document with date field in "collection_trafic"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to aggregate data by date then you need to extract only the date from the timestamp. As it will also contain time.

You can achieve that by using the below query for aggregation.

```
passage_per_hour = collection_trafic.aggregate([{
    '$group': {
        '_id': { '$dateToString': { 'format': "%Y-%m-%d", 'date': '$date' } },
        'amount': { '$sum': {'$toInt' :'$nb_vehicules'}}
    }
}])
```

EDIT:

To filter out null values of date

```
passage_per_hour = collection_trafic.aggregate([
{ 
   '$match':{
        'date':{"$exists":true}
   }
},
{
   '$group': {
       '_id': { '$dateToString': { 'format': "%Y-%m-%d", 'date': '$date' } },
       'amount': { '$sum': {'$toInt' :'$nb_vehicules'}}
    }
}])
```

Comment: I tried this solutions but I have the same results: [capture](https://imgur.com/a/8onDFLa)

Comment: It may return None/null if the date key is not present in the document. To filter out I have updated my answer