Count the dates that overlap with the range
I want to count all items that overlap with the input date range and split them by each date (day of year).
Database:
[
    {
        'params': {
            'name': 'name1',
            'start_time': "2022-02-18 00:11:11"
            'end_time': "2022-02-20 00:11:11",
            'file': "1"
        },
    },
    {
        'params': {
            'name': 'name2',
            'start_time': "2022-02-15 00:11:11"
            'end_time': "2022-02-17 00:11:11",
            'file': '2'
        },
    },
    {
        'params': {
            'name': 'name3',
            'start_time': "2022-02-15 00:00:00"
            'end_time': "2022-02-16 00:11:11",
            'file': '3'
        },
    },

]

Input:
Start date:  2022-02-16
End date:  2022-02-18

Logic:
Input:        |--16--|--17--|--18--|

File1:                      |--18--|--19--|--20--|

File2: |--15--|--16--|

File3: |--15--|--16--|--17--|--18--|--19--|--20--|

Expected result:
{
    {'day': '2022 Day 047', 'count': 2},
    {'day': '2022 Day 048', 'count': 1},
    {'day': '2022 Day 049', 'count': 2},
}

Can anybody help?

This question is similar to: MongoDB find date range if overlap with other dates. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@DarkBee Yes, the first part is the same, but the he want to gorup by the days of the time range, which is very different.

For counting by date, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/57968224/2282634
